# How do you generate CGRects for UIView in a clever way, like CSS divs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

The way I'm currently doing it, the process of creating views manually is a quite dumb.

```
CGRect frameView = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frameView];
```

In what way could I generate rects that are clever, I.e. something like CSS, where if you place divs, they go one after the other downwards; or if they have float set, they would float left one after the other to the right?

Ideally, I want to implement a `UIView` that behaves like a `div` without having to manually set the `origin` and `size` for each view.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having to set things manually because you've chosen to instantiate the views manually. You're asking whether there's an intermediate level, between using the interface builder and having complete control, without using one of the automatic layout containers like a scroll or collection view?

I guess the closest thing would be to apply auto layout constraints. There's a tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) discussing the model behind them and [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSLayoutConstraint) explains how you'd create the objects programmatically.